# Laravel can not use parameter in Order By clause when use raw SQL?

Tags: laravel

Did I find a bug in Laravel?

My code:

```
$this->products = DB::select("select * from products WHERE build_datetime > ? ORDER BY ?, ? limit 3", [$this->oldDate, 'value', 'desc']);
```

It will fail to run. But if I delete the parameter in Order By clause:

```
$this->products = DB::select("select * from products WHERE build_datetime > ? ORDER BY value desc limit 3", [$this->oldDate]);
```

It will work well.

If Laravel can not use parameter in Order By clause when use raw SQL ?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely **you did not find a bug**

You want to use

```
DB::raw(...);
```

not

```
DB::select(...);
```

Comment: I write it according to Laravel Document.

Comment: @neosaga read documentation again; and read this http://fideloper.com/laravel-raw-queries

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Document:

Running Raw SQL Queries

Once you have configured your database connection, you may run queries using the DB facade. The DB facade provides methods for each type of query: select, update, insert, delete, and statement.

Running A Select Query

To run a basic query, we can use the select method on the DB facade:

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show a list of all of the application's users.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $users = DB::select('select * from users where active = ?', [1]);

```
    return view('user.index', ['users' => $users]);
}
```

}
The first argument passed to the select method is the **raw SQL query**, while the second argument is any parameter bindings that need to be bound to the query. Typically, these are the values of the where clause constraints. Parameter binding provides protection against SQL injection.